# Does the air density inside bubbles change with a change in bubble diameter?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, density, surface-tension

As a bubble increases, there is going to be a change to the surface tension in the liquid-gas interface. Hence, as a bubble or to use the more precise terminology; micelle, increase in volume, will the air density remain constant or change?

Answer (score 4):

The pressure inside a bubble is determined by the Young-La Place equation which uses surface tension and the radius of curvature of the bubble film to solve for the pressure rise inside it. The ideal gas law relates pressure to density. Putting these together we get that the net effect is the density of the gas inside the bubble increases above atmospheric as its diameter decreases.

Note however that surface tension forces are not particularly strong, so the density increase will be small until the bubble diameter gets really small (of order ~microns).